# C# Throw being caught in last catch

Tags: c#, exception

I'm wondering if my understanding of `Exception` is incorrect. I have the following code:

```
try
{
   // ... code calls a function which throws a UASException()
}
catch (UASException ex)
{
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new UASException("An unknown error has occured", ex);
}
```

Now when I re-throw the `UASException` it gets caught by the following `Catch`, is this correct? I thought it should return to the calling code with the re-thrown `UASException`.

What could I be missing?

Comment: I sugeest you write "throw new UASException("An unknown error has occured");" in the try block and run the code.

Comment: The code, as it is should work well. I think you're missing something else

Comment: Assuming the exception thrown in the `try` block is an `UASException` it will be rethrown and will never reach the second catch block. If your experience differs, you're most likely encountering some different exception in your code which goes directly to the second catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. Only one exception handler is picked (the one with the best matching exception type). You could have easily tried, but...

---

Example: The following code outputs "Catch 1" and **not** "Catch 2", which is what I'm saying. Only one `catch` is executed, no matter whether an exception occurs within the `catch` block. To catch exceptions within a `catch` block you need to nest `catch` blocks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CSharp
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           try
           {
              throw new ArgumentException("BANG!");
           }
           catch (ArgumentException)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Catch 1");
               throw;
           }
           catch
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Catch 2");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, and this is exactly how I thought it should work. It seems that VS2013 acts slightly differently to previous versions.

Comment: No it does not. Just because it stops at some line in the editor to let you debug doesn't mean the control flow is different. This would render most .NET applications using the latest .NET framework unusable. It may stop there because on upper levels in your code the exception is not caught. Still, the "Catch 2" block is *not ever* executed because of the `throw` in the "Catch 1" block. This is simply not the case.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my comment, this is merely a visual presentation difference between the different versions of VS not a difference in the way the code executes. I expected VS to jump back to the calling function with an exception, which it did not. Maybe I'm just old and confused here. Anyway, without this post I amy still have been fumbling.

Comment: Ah. I see. Actually in previous versions it would have stopped on the line where the error occurred, wouldn't it?